# JSTL dynamic remove tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have a java Constant.java file in which I defined session var name like this :

```
package com.pakageName;

public class Config {
    // name of sessions var
    public static final String ATT_SESSION_USER = "session_user";
    public static final String ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE = "session_message";
    ...
}
```

In Servlet file, I use the following to define session var :

```
session.setAttribute(Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE, "this is the content of the var I wan't to display on the page");
```

The Constant.java file is included in my jsp file using :

```
<%@ page import="com.pakageName.Config" %>
```

So I'm able to get the content of sessionScope var with :

```
// get the content of the session var
${sessionScope[Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE]}
// which return the same result as
${sessionScope.session_message}
```

The question is, how can I remove those session var using remove tag with Constant var value ?

I've tried the following but var attribute doesn't accept el expression ...

```
// throw exception because var attribute doesn't accept el
<c:remove var="${sessionScope[Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE]}" scope="session" />
<c:remove var="${Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE}" scope="session" />
// don't remove anything
<c:remove var="Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE" />
// work but the name is hard coded
<c:remove var="session_message" scope="session" />
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be: `<c:remove var="Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE" scope="session" />`?

Comment: No, because this will try to remove the Constant var and not the session var whose name is the content of Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE (the var is called "session_message")

Comment: Sorry but you are mistaken. Remove a constant? I have no idea what you are on about. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_remove_tag.htm

Comment: I don't want to remove a constant, the constant allow me to store the name of the session var. What I want is to remove the session var whose name is the content of the Constant var. I've edited the post to explain a little more

Answer (score 0):

The problem from what i can see is that you are not actually setting a session variable in the first place. All you're doing there is just calling on a public variable. So when you think you are removing a session variable, you're not actually doing anything. Which is why it persists.

Try actually setting a session variable first with:

```
session.setAttribute("user", Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE);
```

or with JSTL:

```
<c:set var="user" value="${Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE}" scope="session"  />
```

Then remove it with:

```
<c:remove var="user"/>
```

Comment: I already set the session variable in servlet using

    session.setAttribute(Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE, "message sample");

then I call it in the jsp page using 

    ${sessionScope[Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE]}

that's why I can't use remove tag, the name of the var is defined in another file

Comment: First of all, when you set a session variable, the quotes go first!! And secondly once you set a session variable you can only access it by what you wrote in the quotes. So: "session.getAttribute ("messageSample");". You can't have spaces in the variable either...

Comment: I've edited the post to explain a bit more what i try to do : messageSample is the content of the var I store in the session var whose name is session_message : I access the var with session.getAttribute(Constant.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE) which return me "messageSample"

Answer (score 0):

I've find a way to achieve what I want with jsp scriptlet ...

```
<% session.removeAttribute(Config.ATT_SESSION_MESSAGE); %>
```

There is no way to obtain the same result with jstl ?